# How to get row number of "parent" table in React-table from another react table in sub component?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) with "parent" table that has sub component with another react table.

I need to use the row number of the parent in cell editing of the inner table.

I am trying to generate a new prop that will deliver the row.index value of the parent, as in `parentRow = {row.index}` below.
But I fail to pass the row.index value.

**In short: How to pass row.index of parent to react table in sub component?**

Any help is appreciated.

```
      <ReactTable
          data={this.props.data}
          columns = {this.WP2columns}
          pageSize={this.props.data.length+1}
          showPagination={false}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          SubComponent={row => {
            return (
              <div style={{ padding: "0 20px" }}>
                {console.log("WP2 SUBTABLE row=", row) }
                <ReactTable
                  data = {row.original.familywp_goal_tasklist}
                  columns={this.subcolumns}
                  parentRow = {row.index}
                  defaultPageSize={3}
                  showPagination={false}
                />
              </div>
            )
          }}
        />
```

Comment: why it fails ? What error message do you get ? Do you get a proper value ? is `row.index` defined?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- No error. I fail to pass the parameter of the parent row.index to the table in sub component. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: could you provide a js fiddle or jsbin where to reproduce the error, a minimum reproducible code?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- My question is due to lack of documentation... I simply ask how to add a parameter/props value in ReactTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SubComponent use **resolveData** prop to pass parent row index.

```js
      <ReactTable
          data={this.props.data}
          columns = {this.WP2columns}
          pageSize={this.props.data.length+1}
          showPagination={false}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          SubComponent={row => {
            return (
              <div style={{ padding: "0 20px" }}>
                <ReactTable
                  data = {row.original.familywp_goal_tasklist}
                  resolveData={data => data.map(d => {
                    return {
                      ...d,
                      parentRow: row.index
                    }
                  })}
                  columns={this.subcolumns}
                  defaultPageSize={3}
                  showPagination={false}
                />
              </div>
            )
          }}
        />
```

Now in the cell editing parameter you will have **original.parentRow** prop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave up react-table as it recently has many issues and is going through a major change & lack of support. I shall try test it and mark your answer as the correct one.
BTW, where resolveData is documented?